# Isolating ID from query string in redirects with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have this code to change the "?" part of my URL to "/" using .htaccess file.

Example old URL: `bithumor.co/posts?id=13`
New URL after .htaccess rewrite: `bithumor.co/posts/13`

Here's the code:

```
RewriteRule    ^posts/([0-9]+)$    /posts/index.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what, precisely, makes you think anything is going wrong: what URLs are you getting and what should they be instead? Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^posts/([0-9]+)/?$    /posts/index.php?id=$1    [QSA,NC,L]
```

The conditions (RewriteCond) make sure you don't rewrite any existing file/directories on the server.